# gitlab CI/CD: How to trigger only a particular jobs

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I am trying to trigger gitlab CI/CD pipeline of `ProjectA` from `ProjectB`

`gitlab-ci.yml` of `projectB`

```
stages:
  - deploy

staging:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    project: projectA
    branch: main
```

And my `gitlab-ci.yml` of `projectA` is

```
image: docker:19.03.13

stages:
  - build
  - staging

fromprojectB:  <--- when I trigger pipeline from B, I want only this job to run in build stage
  stage: build
  script:
     ..............

fromprojectC:
  stage: build

fromprojectD:
  stage: build
  script:
    .......

deploy-to-stage:
  stage: staging
  script:
     ............
```

I want only the `fromprojectB` job to run among the `build` stage jobs when the pipeline is triggers from `projectB`

How can I do this

Answer (score 0):

You can [pass environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html#pass-cicd-variables-to-a-downstream-pipeline-by-using-the-variables-keyword) from `projectB` and then use them in `rules` in `projectA`.

Example based on your input:

`projectA`:

```
stages:
  - build

fromprojectB:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: '$RUN_JOB_B'
      when: always
    - when: never
      allow_failure: true
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code from project B"
    - echo "Compile complete."

fromprojectC:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: '$RUN_JOB_C'
      when: always
    - when: never
      allow_failure: true
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code from project C"
    - echo "Compile complete."
```

and `projectB`:

```
stages:
  - build

build-job:
  stage: build
  variables:
    RUN_JOB_B: "true"
  trigger:
      project: itersive/internal/rd/projecta
      branch: main
```

Pipeline in `projectB`:

[image]

Pipeline in `projectA`:

[image]

In this setup you cannot run pipeline in `projectA` - all jobs require environment variables - see `rules` section.

Comment: can you show some code, i can understand easily

Comment: @Santhosh answer updated